# jQuery/Ajax success function not rendering html

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a DIV like this `<div id="message"></div>` and trying to add contents to this DIV using `Ajax` success.

This is how my ajax code looks like:

```
    var data = $("form#password_forgotten").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./includes/process_password.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,

        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            $('#message').html(response);
        }           
    });
```

But I can not populate `#message` div with this ajax response. But this ajax coding is working for me and this is what I can get to console.

```
<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert'>
<strong>Oops!</strong> Email address not recognised. Please try another.
</div>
```

Can anybody tell me whats the wrong with this?

Thank you.

Comment: whether the message is logging in the console? any error in your browser console?

Comment: Also log `console.log($('#message').length)`

Comment: No I cannot get any error in my console.

Comment: I can get `1` as a result of `console.log($('#message').length)`

Comment: `console.log(response);` is logging the html content, isn't it

Comment: Yes sir... actually .

Comment: Might be the issue that DOM is not properly loaded...Can you place this Ajax in `document.ready()` function and check please ?

Comment: @TusharGupta, Yes I already placed this code in `document.ready()`

Comment: Actually what would be the problem of this? Thank you.

Comment: Hard code the html and see if that works..$('#message').html('MY TEST CONTENT')

Comment: can you please show us the image of your console log ?

Comment: @TusharGupta, I uploaded an image, find it at -http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=62a54f2

Comment: Now I found my `#message` DIV populating, but its hiding from my page. Like this -  `<div id="message" style="display: none;">
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
<strong>Oops!</strong>
Email address not recognised. Please try another.
</div>
</div>`

Comment: @TusharGupta, Did you found my attached image?

Comment: @user3733831 yes checked the log seems fine....and in the case you described above ....after populating the HTML add `$('#message').show()`

Comment: Yes now its working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***As per the conversation in the comments***

> Now I found my #message DIV populating, but its hiding from my page.
> Like this -  
> **Oops!** Email address not recognised. Please try
> another.  ,

***Summarizing the answer as***

After populating the HTML add `$('#message').show()`