# laravel: view not shown after ajax post

Tags: javascript, laravel

**I want to show a view after ajax post. but view shown only in browser console.not in main browser.what i am doing wrong?? please help. i am stucking here for one week.i am using laravel 5.3**

javascript:

```
$('#btn-save').click(function () {
        var doctor_id=$('#doctors_id').val();
        var doctor_name=$('#autocomplete-custom-append').val();
        var patient=$('#p_name').val();
        var mobile=$('#p_mobile_no').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{URL::to('confirmation')}}',
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'doctor_id':doctor_id,
                'doctor_name': doctor_name,
                'patient_name': patient,
                'mobile_no':mobile

            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
             //window.location.href=data.url;



            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

controller:

```
 public function serialConfirmation(Request $request)
{
    $doctor_id=$request->input('doctor_id');
    $doctor_name=$request->input('doctor_name');
    $patient_name=$request->input('patient_name');
    $mobile_no=$request->input('mobile_no');
    return view('serial.confirmation',compact('doctor_id','doctor_name','patient_name', 'mobile_no' );


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to assing the html to your page you will do this in your javascript like so:

```
$("#wrapper").html(data);
```

If so that you want to put the html to a element with the id of wrapper.

Note this will exchange the current html in the element with the html returned from php if you want to preserve current html and just append the new html you will have to use either prepend or append jquery function depending on if you want to prepend or append.

Comment: in my case how can i use append or prepend so that my view will not change and i pass the variable to view.sorry i am new to javascript.

Comment: @arif  use $( ".YOUR_CLASS_NAME" ).append(data);

Comment: i am using ajax because i have a autocomplete text box to find person from database.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to redirect, there is no need to use ajax, just change the method you call `serialConfirmation` to call your url `/confirmation` then keep the function as you have it.

(You can have a form with `action="{{ url('/confirmation') }}` )

And you can access the data in your view like this {{$doctor_id}}

Comment: i want to redirect to another view with data. how can i do this in success: function (data){}

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `success` like below:

```
success: function (data) {
    // Insert your html code into the page using ".html(html)" method
    // or other similar method.
}
```

Something like [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175742/jquery-ajax-success-function-not-rendering-html).

Comment: thanks to all for your valuable suggestion. my problem is solved. i have wasted so much time by trying posting with ajax where i can use normal post